# how to use Glyphicons in bootstrap 4 and angular2?

Tags: glyphicons, bootstrap-4

I am doing an app with angular-cli and bootstrap4, but when I do some references to Glyphicons, the icons don´t appear. For example, when I add the following code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

I did the bootstrap installation in my angular project with:

```
$ npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

I should make any extra step to have the Glyphicons in bootstrap? Do I should install another npm package specific for Glyphicons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no Glyphicons now in Bootstrap 4 so you'd use another icon package such as FontAwesome or installed the Glyphicons separately.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, Bootstrap 4 doesn't include glyphicon in self release.

I am using FontAwesome and that dependencies in my cases:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

In HTML templates just place a code like that:

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: I started with font-awesome on a project I was doing. I included the icons in a dynamically generated list. I used 4 icons on the right side of each row using *ngFor to create each row in a bootstrap list. The performance was terrible. It took over 30 seconds to display a couple of hundred items. I tested performance and discovered the delay was entirely in the UI. I switched to glyphicon from bootstrap 3 and the page took less than 2 seconds. I don't know if this is because of the SVG format or because it has something to do with font-awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased the entire Glyphicons set and added it to my Angular application. Here is my process:

1. Create a Glyphicons folder in the assets folder here `src/assets/glyphicons`
2. Add `glyphicons.css` to the folder above.
3. Add this in styles.css
   `"styles": ["styles.css", "../src/assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css"],`
4. Create a fonts folder at `src/assets/fonts`
5. Inside the fonts folder place the following files
   -`glyphicons-regular.eot`
   -`glyphicons-regular.svg`
   -`glyphicons-regular.ttf`
   -`glyphicons-regular.woff`
   -`glyphicons-regular.woff2`