# Glyphicon not showing up in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

In this basic angular project, I made it through the Angular CLI. I imported bootstrap to my project through the Angular CLI using `npm install bootstrap --save` from there, I added bootstrap to the `styles.css` by putting `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`.

From there, I created a new component for a favorite icon using the Angular CLI once again. I can confirm the component renders. However, the glyphicon won't show up. I have `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>` in the `favorite.html` component.

When I inspect the element, the glyphicon-star is there in the DOM. However, it is invisible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use Glyphicons in bootstrap 4 and angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634620/how-to-use-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-4-and-angular2)

Comment: For Bootstrap 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365440/how-to-programmatically-use-bootstrap-icons-in-an-angular-project